# How to check token expired or not in passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am using passport JwtStrategy to validate token in my project, but it is sending same error message "Unauthorized" for every errors

If the token expired also it is sending "Unauthorized" status only but I need to get token expired status

Is there any way to implement this logic

```
const passport = require("passport")
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy,
ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt
const opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
opts.secretOrKey = JWT_SECRET


passport.use(
   new JwtStrategy(opts, function (jwt_payload, done) {
    UserID.findOne({ id: jwt_payload._id }, function (err, id) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err, false)
      }
      if (id) {
        return done(null, id)
      } else {
        return done(null, false)
      }
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: From your app perspective, it shouldn't matter why the token was rejected. You shouldn't differentiate behavior for expired or otherwise invalid tokens. If passport returned unauthorized, you should either try to refresh the token (if you have access to a refresh token) or ask the user to log in again. Is there a particular reason why you would need that information? If this really matters you would have to make your own implementation of a passport strategy in which you would verify the JWT by yourself.

Comment: you can check if token is expired by using the exp property of jwt_payload. if Date.now() > jwt_payload.exp, then the token has expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this middleware to send custom token expired message:

```
  export const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }, async (error, token) => {
        if (error || !token) {
            console.log("error", error);
            res.status(401).json({ msg: "token expired" });
        } else {
            next();
        }
        
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

credit does to [this](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/javascript-how-to-return-jwt-token-passport-js#passport-jwt-always-return-401-unauthorized)